# Adding View to a GridView with ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, view

I am trying to add a view to a grid view which has an ArrayAdapter. The logic is that if there is no entry in the database, a button will be added prompting the user to add an entry which is this button :

[image]

But then there is no button added when the app is launched. I am getting no errors as well. here is my code :

**FragmentFood.java**

```
public class FragmentFood extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout layout;
    ArrayList<Items> food = new ArrayList<>();
    ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;
    GridView gridView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food, container, false);
        layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        populateFoods();
        ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(this.getContext(), food);
        gridView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    private void populateFoods() {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getContext());
        try {
            Cursor c = dbHelper.getAllData("food");
            if(c != null) {
                if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                        String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
                        double price = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("price"));
                        food.add(new Items(name, type, price));
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            } else {
                Button btn = new Button(this.getContext());
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_item);
                btn.setText("");
                gridView.addView(btn);
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException sql) {
            Log.e("error", " error sql", sql);
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {


    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Items> item) {
        super(context, 0, item);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Items item = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_button, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        Button itemBtn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemBtn);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        itemBtn.setText(item.getName() + " " + item.getType());
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

There is no data entry in my database and so the addItem button should appear. I have tried adding the view to the parent layout of gridview but no button appears as well. Kindly please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will happen because your adapter size is zero so no view is generated by adapter. In this case you need to pass at least one item in adapter to show button. if don't want to make like that put button in fragment below GridView.

You can addView to grid view like this:

```
    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    populateFoods();
    ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(this.getContext(), food);
    gridView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    View btnView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_button,null);
    gridView.addView(btnView);
    Button itemBtn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemBtn);
```

Comment: would it be possible to add a method in my adapter class, adding a custom button if the passed arraylist is zero?

Comment: no because when zero item is there getView() is not called.

Comment: if you want to add button in grid then pass one element with empty value. and for getting item in getView add +1 position in that

Comment: or you can addview to grid view after calling adapter

Comment: itemsAdapter.getItem().getView() <-- ?? I want to get the button so I can change the background image of that button

Answer (score 0):

In your else code section you are not setting button width & height so it wouldn't show, try following thing:-

```
      //set the properties for button

       Button btn = new Button(this.getContext());
       btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_item);
       btn.setText("");
       gridView.addView(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 
a new item in arraylist and call adapter.notifydatasetchanged